# Regex finding proper pattern for example

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am try to generate a proper pattern. But I couldn't find it.

http://www.sporx.com/tvdebugun/
in this site. i try to capture 
[image]

I am using c#. 
I just created this pattern to capture each lists information's.

```
string pattern =@"<li class="(odd|even)">(.*)<span class="ch-type">(.*)<\/span>(.*)<span class="ch-time">(.*)<\/span>(.*)<div class="ch-desc">(.*)<span class="ch-name">(.*)<\/span>(.*)<span class="ch-text">(.*)<\/span>(.*)<\/div><\/li>"
```

thanks.

Comment: Some people always say: don't parse html with regex. [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)  **You could try something like [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)**

Comment: Are you using `(.*)` in case there are newlines or spaces? I thought `\s*` would work there and be more reliable

Comment: do you have any different approach for this situation

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre i replace new lines to emty strings

Comment: Use html parser it is cleaner and faster and correct. If you can tell the exact logic I can write you what you need.

Comment: Where is the source code? Show us what you want to accomplish before, and after.

Comment: @mybirthname ah so thanks. as the image above , i am try to get each list items information that marked with numbers.

Comment: Show the html code and tell us what you need to take from this html, I can't see html from pictures

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: @mybirthname https://jsfiddle.net/2dzzfmpa/ here is an example. i wrote coment line with number that shows where i want to capture. between the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
(?<=(ch-name">)|(?<=ch-time">)|(?<=ch-type">)|(?<=ch-text">))[\s\S]*?(?=<\/)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/d8PJa9/2